# Eclipse resolve type error

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I've almost done porting this mod but I am failing with this random class that doesn't seem to appear. I ahve already swapped to the new function keys (`getCommandName` -> `getName`)

The source is at https://github.com/Derivates/fpsmod_1.12.2/blob/master/src/main/java/me/dewgs/fpsspoof/FPSSpoofModCommand.java

Here's the log:

```
Details:

Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
Java Version: 1.8.0_152, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 766189632 bytes (730 MB) / 1037959168 bytes (989 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
FML:
Loaded coremods (and transformers):
GL info: ' Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation' Version: '4.6.0 NVIDIA 388.71' Renderer: 'GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2'
[21:58:00] [main/INFO] [FML/]: MinecraftForge v14.23.1.2555 Initialized
[21:58:00] [main/INFO] [FML/]: Starts to replace vanilla recipe ingredients with ore ingredients.
[21:58:00] [main/INFO] [FML/]: Replaced 1036 ore ingredients
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: File C:\Users\juana\Desktop\Mod Porting Tools\forge-1.12.2-14.23.1.2555-mdk\run\config\injectedDependencies.json not found. No dependencies injected
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Building injected Mod Containers [net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLContainer, net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeModContainer]
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Attempting to load mods contained in the minecraft jar file and associated classes
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related directory at C:\Users\juana\Desktop\Mod Porting Tools\forge-1.12.2-14.23.1.2555-mdk\bin, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\minecraft\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.12.2-14.23.1.2555\snapshot\20171003\forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.1.2555.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\3.0.1\f7be08ec23c21485b9b5a1cf1654c2ec8c58168d\jsr305-3.0.1.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\patchy\1.1\aef610b34a1be37fa851825f12372b78424d8903\patchy-1.1.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\9ddf7b048a8d701be231c0f4f95fd986198fd2d8\oshi-core-1.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna\4.4.0\cb208278274bf12ebdb56c61bd7407e6f774d65a\jna-4.4.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\platform\3.4.0\e3f70017be8100d3d6923f50b3d2ee17714e9c13\platform-3.4.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.ibm.icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\63d216a9311cca6be337c1e458e587f99d382b84\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\cdd846cfc4e0f7eefafc02c0f5dce32b9303aa2a\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\97860965d6a0a6b98e7f569f3f966727b8db75\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\21.0\3a3d111be1be1b745edfa7d91678a12d7ed38709\guava-21.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.5\6c6c702c89bfff3cd9e80b04d668c5e190d588c6\commons-lang3-3.5.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\2852e6e05fbb95076fc091f6d1780f1f8fe35e0f\commons-io-2.5.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\4b95f4897fa13f2cd904aee711aeafc0c5295cd8\commons-codec-1.10.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jutils\jutils\1.0.0\e12fe1fda814bd348c1579329c86943d2cd3c6a6\jutils-1.0.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.8.0\c4ba5371a29ac9b2ad6129b1d39ea38750043eff\gson-2.8.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\authlib\1.5.25\9834cdf236c22e84b946bba989e2f94ef5897c3c\authlib-1.5.25.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\realms\1.10.17\e6a623bf93a230b503b0e3ae18c196fcd5aa3299\realms-1.10.17.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\a698750c16740fd5b3871425f4cb3bbaa87f529d\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\18f4247ff4572a074444572cee34647c43e7c9c7\httpclient-4.3.3.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\31fbbff1ddbf98f3aa7377c94d33b0447c646b6e\httpcore-4.3.2.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\it.unimi.dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\9835253257524c1be7ab50c057aa2d418fb72082\fastutil-7.1.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\e801d13612e22cad62a3f4f3fe7fdbe6334a8e72\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\4ac28ff2f1ddf05dae3043a190451e8c46b73c31\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\48fd510879dff266c3815947de66e3d4809f8668\text2speech-1.10.3.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\111e7bea9c968cdb3d06ef4632bf7ff0824d0f36\launchwrapper-1.12.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jline\jline\2.13\2d9530d0a25daffaffda7c35037b046b627bb171\jline-2.13.jar
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-debug-all\5.2\3354e11e2b34215f06dab629ab88e06aca477c19\asm-debug-all-5.2.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.typesafe.akka\akka-actor_2.11\2.3.3\ed62e9fc709ca0f2ff1a3220daa8b70a2870078e\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.typesafe\config\1.2.1\f771f71fdae3df231bcd54d5ca2d57f0bf93f467\config-1.2.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-actors-migration_2.11\1.1.0\dfa8bc42b181d5b9f1a5dd147f8ae308b893eb6f\scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.11.1\56ea2e6c025e0821f28d73ca271218b8dd04926a\scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.plugins\scala-continuations-library_2.11\1.0.2\e517c53a7e9acd6b1668c5a35eccbaa3bab9aac\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.plugins\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\1.0.2\f361a3283452c57fa30c1ee69448995de23c60f7\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.11.1\e11da23da3eabab9f4777b9220e60d44c1aab6a\scala-library-2.11.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\f05d7345bf5a58924f2837c6c1f4d73a938e1ff0\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.11.1\6580347e61cc7f8e802941e7fde40fa83b8badeb\scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-swing_2.11\1.0.1\b1cdd92bd47b1e1837139c1c53020e86bb9112ae\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.2\820fbca7e524b530fdadc594c39d49a21ea0337e\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\lzma\lzma\0.0.1\521616dc7487b42bef0e803bd2fa3faf668101d7\lzma-0.0.1.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\42ccaf4761f0dfdfa805c9e340d99a755907e2dd\trove4j-3.0.3.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\c73b5636faf089d9f00e8732a829577de25237ee\codecjorbis-20101023.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\codecwav\20101023\12f031cfe88fef5c1dd36c563c0a3a69bd7261da\codecwav-20101023.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\5c5e304366f75f9eaa2e8cca546a1fb6109348b3\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\73e80d0794c39665aec3f62eee88ca91676674ef\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\419c05fe9be71f792b2d76cfc9b67f1ed0fec7f6\soundsystem-20120107.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput\2.0.5\39c7796b469a600f72380316f6b1f11db6c2c7c4\jinput-2.0.5.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\697517568c68e78ae0b4544145af031c81082dfe\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\d51a7c040a721d13efdfbd34f8b257b2df882ad0\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\java3d\vecmath\1.5.2\79846ba34cbd89e2422d74d53752f993dcc2ccaf\vecmath-1.5.2.jar
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ca.weblite\java-objc-bridge\1.0.0\6ef160c3133a78de015830860197602ca1c855d3\java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\655c643309c2f45a56a747fda70e3fadf57e9f11\jansi-1.11.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.scala-lang\scala-actors\2.11.0\8ccfb6541de179bb1c4d45cf414acee069b7f78b\scala-actors-2.11.0.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\7ff832a6eb9ab6a767f1ade2b548092d0fa64795\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\385ee093e01f587f30ee1c8a2ee7d408fd732e16\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\53f9c919f34d2ca9de8c51fc4e1e8282029a9232\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\b84d5102b9dbfabfeb5e43c7e2828d98a7fc80e0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\931074f46c795d2f7b30ed6395df5715cfd7675b\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-linux.jar
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Skipping known library file C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\bcab850f8f487c3f4c4dbabde778bb82bd1a40ed\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-osx.jar
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\minecraft\deobfedDeps\compileDummy.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related file at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\minecraft\deobfedDeps\providedDummy.jar, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found a minecraft related directory at C:\Users\juana\.gradle\caches\minecraft\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.12.2-14.23.1.2555\start, examining for mod candidates
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Minecraft jar mods loaded successfully
[21:58:00] [main/INFO] [FML/]: Found 0 mods from the command line. Injecting into mod discoverer
[21:58:00] [main/INFO] [FML/]: Searching C:\Users\juana\Desktop\Mod Porting Tools\forge-1.12.2-14.23.1.2555-mdk\run\mods for mods
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining directory bin for potential mods
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Found an mcmod.info file in directory bin
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Recursing into package me
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Recursing into package me/dewgs
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Recursing into package me/dewgs/fpsspoof
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Identified a mod of type Lnet/minecraftforge/fml/common/Mod; (me.dewgs.fpsspoof.FPSSpoofMod) - loading
[21:58:00] [main/TRACE] [fpsspoofmod/]: Parsed dependency info : Requirements: [] After:[] Before:[]
[21:58:00] [main/INFO] [fpsspoofmod/]: Mod fpsspoofmod is missing the required element 'name'. Substituting fpsspoofmod
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.1.2555.jar for potential mods
[21:58:00] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.1.2555.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file jsr305-3.0.1.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container jsr305-3.0.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file patchy-1.1.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container patchy-1.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file text2speech-1.10.3.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container text2speech-1.10.3.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file asm-debug-all-5.2.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container asm-debug-all-5.2.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file jansi-1.11.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container jansi-1.11.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file compileDummy.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container compileDummy.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file providedDummy.jar for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container providedDummy.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining directory start for potential mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: No mcmod.info file found in directory start
[21:58:01] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Recursing into package net
[21:58:01] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Recursing into package net/minecraftforge
[21:58:01] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Recursing into package net/minecraftforge/gradle
[21:58:01] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Recursing into package net/minecraftforge/gradle/tweakers
[21:58:01] [main/INFO] [FML/]: Forge Mod Loader has identified 5 mods to load
[21:58:01] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Received a system property request ''
[21:58:01] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: System property request managing the state of 0 mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: After merging, found state information for 0 mods
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [Forge Mod Loader/]: Mod Forge Mod Loader is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [Minecraft Forge/]: Mod Minecraft Forge is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [fpsspoofmod/]: Enabling mod fpsspoofmod
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [fpsspoofmod/]: Mod fpsspoofmod is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[21:58:01] [main/TRACE] [FML/]: Verifying mod requirements are satisfied
[21:58:01] [main/FATAL] [FML/]: The mod fpsspoofmod does not wish to run in Minecraft version Minecraft 1.12.2. You will have to remove it to play.
[21:58:01] [main/FATAL] [FML/]: Wrong Minecraft version for fpsspoofmod
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Mod sorting data
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: fpsspoofmod(fpsspoofmod:1.01): bin ()
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Loading Resources - Default took 0.006s
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Loading Resources - FMLFileResourcePack:Forge Mod Loader took 0.009s
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Loading Resources - FMLFileResourcePack:Minecraft Forge took 0.008s
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Loading Resources - FMLFileResourcePack:fpsspoofmod took 0.000s
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Reloading - LanguageManager took 0.016s
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Loading Resources - Reloading listeners took 0.017s
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resources took 0.041s
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [Forge Mod Loader/]: Mod Forge Mod Loader is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [Minecraft Forge/]: Mod Minecraft Forge is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [fpsspoofmod/]: Mod fpsspoofmod is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[21:58:01] [main/WARN] [FML/]: There were errors previously. Not beginning mod initialization phase
[21:58:01] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - TextureManager took 0.000s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - SoundHandler took 1.837s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - FontRenderer took 0.002s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - FontRenderer took 0.002s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - GrassColorReloadListener took 0.010s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - FoliageColorReloadListener took 0.007s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Rendering Setup - GL Setup took 0.002s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Rendering Setup - Loading Texture Map took 0.009s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - B3DLoader took 0.000s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - OBJLoader took 0.000s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - ModelFluid$FluidLoader took 0.000s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - ItemLayerModel$Loader took 0.000s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - MultiLayerModel$Loader took 0.000s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - ModelDynBucket$LoaderDynBucket took 0.000s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - ModelManager took 0.205s
[21:58:03] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Rendering Setup - Loading Model Manager took 0.298s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - RenderItem took 0.002s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Rendering Setup - Loading Item Renderer took 0.260s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - EntityRenderer took 0.000s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - BlockRendererDispatcher took 0.000s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - RenderGlobal took 0.000s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Loading Resource - SearchTreeManager took 0.082s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Step: Rendering Setup - Loading Entity Renderer took 0.457s
[21:58:04] [main/DEBUG] [FML/]: Bar Finished: Rendering Setup took 1.025s
```

And also here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure if the issue is caused by a missing class which isn't present in the original jar file.

Comment: Please post the code in your question, not in links.

Comment: I added that in code with CTRL+K but it says i exceed the limit, sorry any inconveniences.

Comment: Please shorten your code so it fits here. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully it's easy to read, thanks in advance.

Comment: Refined it for you.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for bothering I'm just trying to make everything clear and read-able. Sorry again, any help?

Comment: You are either missing an jar or forgot to add the import. Seems to be using this [API](https://takahikokawasaki.github.io/minecraft-resources/javadoc/forge/1.8-11.14.1.1320/net/minecraft/util/IChatComponent.html). (class and sublcass matches). FYI: don't use images like this. Paste the error message and a small code that show what your a doing (in text)

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you provided, you showed that you were sending a message by doing `Minecraft.getMinecraft().player.sendMessage`which means that the command will only work client side and will cause a crash server side.

The method already adds the ability to send back through the argument `sender` which allows you to access to the `sendMessage` method which will work server side as well as client side sending a message to that entity.

Also, `ChatComponentText` is now called `TextComponentString` I believe.